# Record video a particular area and a view element in application

Tags: android, streaming, webrtc, record

I want to record WEBRTC streaming but i did't find any solution in mobile side on WEBRTC documents.
so I decide to record screen a particular area and view to fixed this.

In WEBRTC use

```
<org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

view for play streaming.
We can't find any solution for record this SurfaceViewRenderer. so we use and save this recording locally as well server

Please suggest me any solution ...

Comment: Did you solve this?  If not, you might want to change the [record] tag to one about "recording"...

Comment: @Aakash Yadav Did you find any solution?